# String transformation by performing lowercase to uppercase conversion and lowercase deletion

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am trying to understand this algorithm: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-possible-transform-one-string-another/. I came up with my own idea to solve this task. The problem is I think my solution is O(n + m) complexity, which seems strange, because the shown solution is O(nm)

My code:

```
bool check(string s1, string s2) {
  int tmp = 0;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < s2.length(); ++i) {
    int pos = s1.substr(tmp).find(s2[i]);

    if (pos == string::npos) {
      pos = s1.substr(tmp).find(tolower(s2[i]));
    }

    if (pos == string::npos) {
      return false;
    }

    pos += tmp;

    for (int j = tmp; j < pos; ++j) {
      if (isupper(s1[j])) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    tmp = pos + 1;
  }

  return true;
}
```

I know find method is complexity O(n*m) but in this case, I am looking only for single char in string, so the complexity of this is O(n). Can any one enlighten me what I've done wrong? Or just show a test case that i miss.

Comment: Loop in a loop? *O(N²)*.

Comment: Are you sure, because I iterate using substrings, and this is not casual loop in a loop situation.

Comment: I think an *O(N)* solution is possible where you treat this as a state machine.

Comment: It's a loop in a loop. Automatic *O(N²)* unless your inner loop is bounded to a constant. Yours is not, it's dependent on the length of the strings.

Comment: Each char in string s1 is iterated 3 times in worst case. doesn't matter how long the string s2 is.

Comment: Why 3 times? Why not once? You could probably compile this into a regular expresion that's *O(N)* time.

Comment: I don't know how would compiler treat this, but that's not the point. You are probably right with the O(N^2) complexity, but I totally can not see this, because for me the inner loop is in some way bounded. In my understanding  string s1 would be iterated constant number of times and string s2 would be iterated constant number of times, therefore O(n + m)

Comment: Easy way to find out is to do this empirically. Compute the time necessary to perform the operation versus varying values of *N*. The shape of the resulting curve doesn't lie. Remember, at small values of *N* the results of *O(N)* and *O(N²)* are hard to distinguish but the results become dramatic when N > 1e6, etc. You can usually tell using powers of 10, like N=1, 10, 100, 1000, etc.

Comment: @Geog what do you mean "bounded in some way"? Even a simple N^2 loop is bounded

Comment: Each time we start iterating through s1 (inner loop) we start at the element we finished previously. So it's not typical loop in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found answer by myself. I believe that algorithm shown above is O(n + m), but it doesn't solve properly all of the cases. Example case that fails s1 = "aA", s2 = "AA".